# mysql trigger to calculate a duration based on starttime and endtime

Tags: mysql, triggers, duration

I want to make a trigger to calculate an entry duration in hours.

I have the following code, but it's incorrect and i don't know why.

```
create trigger Calculate_Duration
before insert or update on Tbl_Eventos

for each row
declare
begin
    :new.duration := :new.endtime - :new.starttime
END;
```

and my table is like this:

[image: Table]

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.7.6+ you might want to consider a generated column instead of a trigger. [Generated Column Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: I'm using '5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'

Comment: Yep, that's more recent than 5.7.6 and you should be able to use them.

Comment: and if the starttime or endtime changes?

Comment: Then the duration value will change accordingly. Internally, this will happen when the time changes take place (for STORED GENERATED COLUMNs) or when the expression is evaluated on SELECT (for VIRTUAL GENERATED COLUMNs).

Answer (score 0):

let's try this,

it will work

```
CREATE TRIGGER Calculate_Duration BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Tbl_Eventos FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.duration = TIMEDIFF(NEW.endtime, NEW.starttime);
```

Comment: How do I create an if condition, example. if starttime=8:00 and endtime=18:00 then duration = 8:00

Comment: I've done it like this: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER Calculate_Duration_insert BEFORE INSERT ON Tbl_Eventos 
FOR EACH ROW 
IF TIMEDIFF(NEW.endtime, NEW.starttime) > 80000 THEN 
 SET NEW.duration = '8:00:00';
ELSE
 SET NEW.duration = TIMEDIFF(NEW.endtime, NEW.starttime);
END IF